# How do horns get mechanically voiced in a 125 key Gaudin dance organ (or other mechanical orchestra)?

Tags: instruments, brass

Sample video here:

I understand with the organ pipes that they would have a blower and be able to actuate a valve to make them sound but how do they make the horns sound? You need air blowing through lips so what do they use for the lips in this case? Just some rubber?

Having trouble finding any info on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like [trompettes en chamade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/En_chamade) to me, in German "Spanische Trompeten".  The sounding bits are metal "reeds" vibrating against a shallot.  That's in contrast to free reeds (like those used in accordions and harmoniums) which solely work through interruption of the air stream by a reed passing through a reed gap rather than hitting anything.  This basic single-reed mechanism then is amplified with a resonance cone.  They are among the loudest reed pipes and pretty popular on fair or theatre organs.

Comment: I see so sort of like a duck call

Comment: So it's like reed registers/stops in regular organs?